# React router will keep its state data even after a browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I do programmatic navigation using some state data like this

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/some/path', 
  search: '?the=query',
  state: { data: someData }
})
```

I thought react-router would make `state.data` to be `undefined` when a situation like a page refresh or a manual URL typing, but it doesn't remove the `state.data` in both scenarios

Actually what I want to do is, redirect to an another component if there is no data for the `state.data` property

```
if (!props.location.state.data) {
  history.push('/')
}
```

How can I do that, this is a bit confusing though, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer from here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState

```
window.history.replaceState(null, '')
```